# Why does my render result look different from my viewer node, and how can I fix it?

Tags: model, 3d, nodes, render, blender

Im working with blender and I made planet earth, but there is a problem.
In my viewer node, the result looks a lot better than the result when I render. How can I make the render result look the same as the viewer node?
[At the top you can see the viewer node and in the bottom left the render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6kFJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the compositing nodes, the [Viewer node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/output/viewer.html) is what is shown in the node editor background, the [Composite node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/output/composite.html) is what is seen in the final render.

You have the composite node connected to the render layers node while the viewer node is connected after you have added the glare. Connect the composite node to the same glare node as the viewer to get the final render to match up.

[image: connection neede for result]